# Jmeter - Need to check empty tags in SOAP request

Tags: jmeter

I have a SOAP request. I need to use jmeter to test multiple requests for same method, each time passing one missing element.

How can I achieve this ?

I tried writing the tags into csv using CSV data config , but I am unable to enter empty values in the csv, each time for a different tag in each csv row.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV Data Set Config will read the value from next line only on the next iteration of the thread (virtual user), you cannot read more than one line within the bounds of a single iteration. You might want to take a look at [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) where it's you who decides when to proceed to the next line.

If the __CSVRead() function isn't applicable for your use case be aware that you can build a request body, i.e. XML from CSV file using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor).

See [Creating XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml) chapter of Groovy documentation for more details.